# Address of object in Julia

Tags: julia

How do I get the address of an object `obj` as a plain string? The `pointer_from_objref()` function is close to what I want, but when I print the result I get `"Ptr{Void} @0x00007f3864c40038"` instead of `"0x00007f3864c40038"`. Of course, I could simply discard the first 11 characters, but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution.

The motivation for this question is that I am working on an adjacency list based graph library, centred around the type

```
immutable Vertex
    neighbors::Vector{Vertex}
end
```

At the moment, printing a single vertex recursively prints the entire graph, which is very inconvenient. Instead, I would like `print(v)` to result in `Vertex 0x00007f3864c40038`.

Comment: OT, but I assume you know about https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/LightGraphs.jl and https://github.com/JuliaLang/Graphs.jl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `repr` + `UInt64` is a way:

```
julia> a=10
10

julia> s=repr(UInt64(pointer_from_objref(a)))
"0x0000000080012230"

julia> print(s)
0x0000000080012230
```

<sub>tested with `Julia Version 0.4.3`</sub>

---

*Update*: in Julia version >= 1.0, [`pointer_from_objref`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.pointer_from_objref) may not be called on immutable objects, so for the example above works, the `a` variable needs to be setted to a mutable type (e.g., an `Array` type):

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> s=repr(UInt64(pointer_from_objref(a)))
"0x000000001214ce80"
```

Comment: What about the immutable type?

Comment: @RubemPacelli I provided an example, on how it can be done. (It is dangerous to do however)

Answer (score 2):

In Julia 1.7

You can do this in two ways.

For mutable types such as structs:

```
   julia> mutable struct foo
       a
       end

    julia> tst = foo(1)
    foo(1)
    julia> s=repr(UInt64(pointer_from_objref(a)))
```

However, as of Julia >= 1.0 this can not be used on immutable objects.
Note the check in the function below:

```
function pointer_from_objref(@nospecialize(x))
    @_inline_meta
    ismutable(x) || error("pointer_from_objref cannot be used on immutable objects")
    ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), x)
end
```

To do this on immutable objects (**which is dangerous, since the memory address of those objects is not static**)

One can provide another method skipping the check:

```
function unsafe_pointer_from_objectref(@nospecialize(x))
    #= Warning Danger=#
    ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), x)
end
```

```
julia> struct bar
       a
       end

julia> tst = bar(1)
    bar(1)
julia> repr(UInt64(unsafe_pointer_from_objectref(tst)))
"0x000000009316f360"
```